# What does "[\\-\\s]" mean in an ICU regular expression?

Tags: regex

I'm looking at a longer ICU regular expression that contains:

```
[\\-\\s]
```

The limits of my understanding is the brackets and the "-", so I'm thinking it means:

match a character, in the range of literal-backslash to any-whitespace...

But how do you do that? Shouldn't a range be two distinct points in the character space, like the classic "[a-z]" ?

If it helps:

> The "\s" is "Match a white space character. White space is defined as [\t\n\f\r\p{Z}].

[Regular Expressions - ICU User Guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Comment: It is not a range, it only matches a `-` or any whitespace. Someone just overescaped the pattern, `"[-\\s]"` is the same. Could you please show full relevant code? Is it Swift?

Comment: Its in Swift, but I can't share the full expression.  :(

I did peel it apart isolate it. Isn't "\\" valid in a set as the backslash-escaped? Thats what really confused me.

Comment: I added 2 close reasons explaining what the backslashes and regex denote.